# Voiceover reading all cells inside tableview

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have one tableview. I can read cell by cell with right and left swiping. But i want to start reading from first cell to last cell automatically. Now it is reading first cell than stopped.

After first cell's reading finished, it should focus second cell and start reading than third so on...

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: hi berker,is this purpose solved?i also need to implement with automatic scrolling ,any idea to acheive this?

Comment: hey, unfortunately Apple didn't allow to achieve this programmatically. If users wants to start auto reading, they can use  flick down with 2 fingers to auto scroll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I achieve this?

To read automatically all the accessible cells from the first one, just **flick up 2 fingers** anywhere on the screen.
[image]

If you want to do the same action from the current selection, **flick down with 2 fingers** anywhere on the screen.
[image]

When you want to stop the automatic scrolling, **double-tap with 2 fingers** anywhere on the screen.

If you need more information about many useful VoiceOver gestures, take a look at [this site](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/voiceover.html#tips-tricks).

Comment: So is this a normal behaviour when using voiceover? How users understand that there are more cells to read? For example I am adding text blocks to each cell and these text blocks are connected. I tried to add text blocks to uitextview but swiping left and right only line by line. Not blocks by blocks. So i decided to use tableview cells.

Comment: VoiceOver users discover the a11y elements either with multiple swipes or automatically as described (the item chooser list may also be a choice).
It's very important to understand that they receive this information step by step and not as a whole as we do by looking at the screen: super design must be well studied before being implemented without thinking of a11y.
I don't really understand your use case: please add detailed information and illustrations in another question if you need iOS developers advice about this situation.  ;o)